# create a test project inside a project(which we want to test) in Eclipse android?

Tags: android, testing, junit

There are two ways of creating test project for a library project which you want to test
**First way**:Create a test project separately.I know this way.
**Second Way**:Create a test project inside the project itself ,But I dont know how to create a test project inside a project(which we want to test).
Could any one please help and provide the steps to follow to create the test project inside the project without creating a separate test project.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

The way described in the on-line documentation is to create a new test project and store it within a "tests" directory underneath the project.  It'll contain what looks to be a complete, normal Android project.

Look under "Test Projects" here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html